# How can I fetch data from different tables database using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web application using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I want to fetch data from database using AngularJS.

My issue is that I have two tables (products, category) like below:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string imgurl { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I want to iterate data using `ng-repeat` from product table like this :

```
Name   category
================
iphone  -  Mobiles
```

Only, I can retrieve data like :

```
Name   category Id
================
iphone  -  1
```

I can’t retrieve category name from category table. but I can retrieve categoryId.

Is there any way to get data from database in this format using `ng-repeat` .

```
 Name   category
  ================
 iphone  -  Mobiles
```

I want to get data from two tables already between them relationship .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your data access api ? Entity framework or else ?

Comment: can you show the query where you are using?

Comment: entity framework 

`public JsonResult getAllProducts() 
        {
            var products = db.Products.ToList();
            return Json(products , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`

Comment: Wouldnt this be a server-side thing for how certain api requests are handled?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as shown below (using [**Eager Loading**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx))

```
public JsonResult getAllProducts() 
 { 
      var products = db.Products
                     .Include(p => p.Category)
                     .ToList();

      return Json(products , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
 }
```

**Update :** You cannot retrieve collection of objects through the `get` method.You have to use `post` with the object collection as shown below.This is just a sample.Hope you can get the idea.

```
 public async Task<RefereeEditDto> GetRefereeForEditAsync(NullableIdInput<int> input)
        {
            var referee = await _refereeRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == input.Id);
            var result = referee.MapTo<RefereeEditDto>();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately , dosen’t  work and cant retrieve any data

Comment: What is the status of `products ` when you put a debug there ? Are there any data on it with `category` or what ?

Comment: You have to go next step (next line).

Comment: when i inspect element in chrome, i got his error 
 `angular.js:13424 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest`

Comment: is that mean do you have data for the category on above query when you do the debug ? You have to sort out that issue first.

Comment: now i can got data from database when i debug code, but how can i retrieve these data using ng-repeat 
 `<tr ng-repeat="product in products" >
                <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
<td>{{product.Category.Name}}</td>`

when i use this code like above i can nor retrieve any data in browser

Comment: can you show how you have filled the `products` collection on `js` file ?

Comment: Servics.Js

   ` 
this.getAllProducts = function () {
        return $http.get("/Home/getAllProducts");
    };
 `
controller.js:
   ` function AllProducts() {
        var productsdata = testservice.getAllProducts();
        productsdata.then(function (product) {
            $scope.products = product.data;
        }, function () {
            alert("error about retrive products");
        });
    }; `

Comment: You must use `post` method.

Comment: same error when i change get to post .. no data ... is there problem in ng-repeat

Comment: Please Sampath , i can’t got the idea ... can you give me a code using my classes as shown above ... i want to know what do you mean.. please sampath

Comment: Please read this.http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Transfer-Objects

Answer (score 0):

Finally , i found the solution of my issue ... as follows:

query to join between two tables :

```
 public JsonResult getAllProducts() 
    {
        var products = from pr in db.Products
                       join ct in db.Categories
                       on pr.CategoryId equals ct.Id
                       select new
                       {
                           pr.Name,
                           pr.CategoryId,
                          CatName= ct.Name
                       };
            return Json(products , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

                    }
```

after that , using ng-repeat to iterate data :

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products" >
                <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.CatName}}</td>
                <td>{{product.CategoryId}}</td></tr>
```

Now , every things working fine and i can fetch data in which format i want... thanks to every one trying to help me.